# I have added a anchor tag with text "Read more" but there is some error with the styling

Tags: css

As you can see in the image below, the anchor tag is not the best looking:

[image: 1]

```
 <div class="news_1">
  <img class="img" src="" alt="Loading">

  <div class="data"></div>
  <a class="read_more" href="">Read more</a>
</div>
```

I have a bunch of these as containers for displaying news

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3d3b3b;
}
.news_1{
  width: 65%;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 3ex;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121); 
}
img{
  width: 40%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.data{
  display: inline;
  padding: 1ex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.read_more{  
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
  overflow: hidden;
}
input{
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin: 3.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
h1{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

This is the css

I want the anchor tag to be in the blue area:

[image: 2]

Not quite sure what to do. I am still a beginner. I would be extremely grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to handle this. Since you have already set the 'news_1' to display: flex, we'll go that route. Please note I used "placecage.com" and lorem ipsum for demo purposes only.

As you see, the flex items inside the div "news_1" will be displayed horizontally by default.

Place the image on the left in its own div

Place the text and read more in its own div

Also please note you should set news_1 css prop: align-items: center;

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #3d3b3b;
}
.news_1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121); 
}
img{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.data{
  display: block;
  padding: 1ex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.read_more{  
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121);
  position: relative;
}
input{
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 5vh;
  margin: 3.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}
h1{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
 <div class="news_1">
   <div class="image-left">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.placecage.com/550/300">
   </div>
   <div class="text-right">
   <div class="data">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget ultrices elit.</div>
    <a href="#" class="read_more">Read more</a>
   </div>
</div>
```